# Help with Wp Query

Tags: wp-query

I have a custom post type, and using wp query I am wanting to display posts only by authors with a specific role. How can I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

```
$authors = get_users( array(
    'fields' => 'ID',
    'role' => 'your_role'
));

$my_query = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'your_post_type',
    'author' => implode( ',', $authors )
));
```